# Code definition window in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a code definition window in Intellij IDEA? I am aware that there is Quick Definition view, but I don't like it, because it closes automatically as soon as it loses focus. I want it to stay open and show the definition of the identifier under the cursor. Maybe there is a plugin that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Quick Definition` window can be pinned, it will open as a tab in `Find` panel, however it will not update automatically and if you open a new definition, it will appear in a popup again. [Feature request is welcome](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA#newissue=yes).